# Android 11 ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE: set initial URI to the Documents folder

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

using the Scoped Storage model in Android 11 I want to give the user the ability to choose a folder, starting in the documents folder:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,    ???     )
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE,null)
```

The problem is, how can I generate a proper URI of the phone's documents folder? (It sits just in root / ) In the official documentation, no examples are given. I really hope there are some neat constants for all the standard locations?

Comment: "The problem is, how can I generate a proper URI of the phone's documents folder?" -- AFAIK, there is no option for that, sorry. `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` is designed to be some `Uri` that you obtained previously from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We will manupilate `INITIAL_URI` obtained from `StorageManager..getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()`.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
    //String startDir = "Android";
    //String startDir = "Download"; // Not choosable on an Android 11 device
    //String startDir = "DCIM";
    //String startDir = "DCIM/Camera";  // replace "/", "%2F"
    //String startDir = "DCIM%2FCamera";
    String startDir = "Documents";

    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

    String scheme = uri.toString();

    Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

    scheme += "%3A" + startDir;

    uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

    Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());

    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    return;
}
```

Comment: You are making assumptions about the `Uri` format; those assumptions may not be stable across Android versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out. It is good enough if it works for most phones, as long as it doesn't crash on the others. Its the "better than nothing" approach.

Comment: Will this work in android-9 and below versions ?

Comment: `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)`

Comment: Hopefully, the Android team will have this fixed with a standard implementation in a future Android version if the above solution breaks.

Comment: thx, works for "/Android/data"

Comment: For Android 13 this does not work anymore.

Comment: @blackapps I tested it, and it's working well in  `android 13 virtual device` (Emulator). Can I get any references for this update?

Comment: It did not work on my Android 13 device. That's why i reported.

Comment: I tested on my Pixel 5a Android 13 and it works.

Comment: Yes fresh installing is working, but when you test with update app it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

> how can I generate a proper URI of the phone's documents folder?

Tested on :

1. **Xiaomi M2102J20SI**
2. **Emulator Pixel 4 XL API 30**

Function `askPermission()` opens the target directory.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun askPermission() {
    val storageManager = application.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val intent =  storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()

    val targetDirectory = "WhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses" // add your directory to be selected by the user
    var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI") as Uri
    var scheme = uri.toString()
    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/")
    scheme += "%3A$targetDirectory"
    uri = Uri.parse(scheme)
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Uri of the file will be returned in `onActivityResult()`

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {
                data.data?.let { treeUri ->

                    // treeUri is the Uri of the file
                    
                   // if life long access is required the takePersistableUriPermission() is used

                    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                            treeUri,
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    )

                  readSDK30(treeUri)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Function `readSDK30()` is used to read files & folders from `Uri`

```
  private fun readSDK30(treeUri: Uri) {
        val tree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri)!!

        thread {
            val uriList  = arrayListOf<Uri>()
            listFiles(tree).forEach { uri ->
                 
                // Collect all the Uri from here
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Function `listFiles()` returns all the files & folders in the given `Uri`

```
fun listFiles(folder: DocumentFile): List<Uri> {
            return if (folder.isDirectory) {
                folder.listFiles().mapNotNull { file ->
                    if (file.name != null) file.uri else null
                }
            } else {
                emptyList()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that basically tells how to use Scoped Storage for a random starting directory. Thanks for the clean code. Unfortunately, my question was how to use Scoped Storage for a FIXED starting directory that the user must not choose himself.

Comment: @Kenobi, how to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE........ It has nothing to do with scoped storage...

Comment: How can we fetch properties like duration, resolution (if file is video) from documentfile object?

Comment: This does not work for me on Android 12.

Comment: @Himanshu i no longer work in android

Answer (score 4):

All the credit goes to the above @blackapp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67554693/2036264)!

Here is the same code in Kotlin language:

```kotlin
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val sm =  getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    intent = sm.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
    //String startDir = "Android";
    //String startDir = "Download"; // Not choosable on an Android 11 device
    //String startDir = "DCIM";
    //String startDir = "DCIM/Camera";  // replace "/", "%2F"
    //String startDir = "DCIM%2FCamera";
    val startDir = "Documents"
    var uriroot = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI")    // get system root uri
    var scheme = uriroot.toString()
    Log.d("Debug", "INITIAL_URI scheme: $scheme")
    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/")
    scheme += "%3A$startDir"                        //change uri to Documents folder
    uriroot = Uri.parse(scheme)
    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uriroot)                        // give changed uri to Intent
    Log.d("Debug", "uri: $uriroot")
  
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

As some commentors mentioned, this code might break and not work in the future, which is true. However, considering Android's past, they will change the storage API anyways every other year.

Comment: Please post your Kotlin code again at the post mentioned at top 'question already has an answer here: ' Visiters of this page here will look no further so i think your code is better there.

Comment: when i am update updated SDK 33 apk on old apk SDK 29 version - the "Use this Folder" permission is grant but, i am not able to access that folder file 

I am accessing music file which is downloaded inside device "Music" folder with my application name.