# Android 11 Access other apps Data in Android/media

Tags: android, permissions, storage

I've an WhatsApp Status Saver app and want to update it cause WhatsApp changed the path. The path I want to access is:

/sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/

Unfortunately Google changed permissions when it comes to Storage Access.

Is there any way to access the folder with the Mediastore API or the Storage Access Framework?

I tried this with the Storage Access Framework (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files):

Code:

```
openDirectory(Uri.fromFile("/sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/"));

public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
           
        }
    }
}
```

Normally it should open the path to grant permissions but that doesn't work, it opens the last directory. Also it's not possible to select the folder manual because it's hidden.

Thanks

Comment: /sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/

Comment: Your app has access to that folder but will not normally see files of other apps. Only if the app got 'all files access'. The MediaStore has no access to Android directory. But SAF has.

Comment: Yeah I tried with SAF to open the path but that doesnt work, do you have a sample code?

Comment: Well what did you try? How do you want to use saf? Which action used? Post your code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: After selecting the folder I want to copy the files into a public directory like DCIM

Comment: Well ok. What is the problem doing so? And indeed INITIAL_URI does not work the way you thought it would. Better remove all INITIAL_URI stuff. The gui will not open there. But the user can browse to it.

Comment: INITIAL URI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-scoped-storage-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder/67554693

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, thank you so far :)

Comment: Browsing to it isn't possible.The reason why is that the folder is hidden (.Statuses)

Comment: It is possible but the user has to go to the menu of the gui and enable 'show hidden files'.

Comment: Recently I checked the path but still its storing media in older path. Not sure is it for particular WhatsApp version only ?

Comment: @Smeet I have the beta version installed, maybe that's the reason why I've another path.

Comment: @MarvinStelter Now its changed to new path. I guess whatsapp is changing to new path in some groups of devices. Now I think all are migrated to new path.

Comment: Would make sense and I'm using Android 11, so it must be android/media with api level 30