# Opening download directory using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-external-storage

I'm trying to open the download directory in my emulator using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

I can successfully get the path of the downloads directory and list all the files in it, but I can't seem to open it with an intent. It only displays the `Recent` directory.

Successfully logs all the files in that download directory, so the path to it is not incorrect

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
File[] files = f.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
     for (File inFile : files) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionGranted: File name: " + inFile.getName());;
     }
}
```

But when using the intent:

```
public void openDirectory() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());

        Log.d(TAG, "openDirectory: " + uri);
        //logs this: /storage/emulated/0/Download
        

        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "file/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select keystore"));
    }
```

It always displays `Recent`

[image]

Instead of `Downloads`

[image]

I have to manually go to the `Downloads` tab

[image]

How can I make it so that the intent goes to the `Downloads` without having the need to switch?

Comment: Did you tried `DownloadManager` ?

Comment: No I didn't. Why would I use download manager?

Comment: Google for INITIAL_URI.

Comment: `openDirectory()` Pretty confusing function name. Better would be selectFile() or selectFileWithActionGetContent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How would I be able to display only one file type ```.keystore```  and be able to select it?

Comment: I am not sure but i think you cant do that because we can only send pre defined type as an type to intent.I searched for keystore extension intent but didnt find any.So there is no support for .keystore type as an extension.

Comment: You cannot select a file now either. Well the user can select a file but your app will not be informed. If you want to select a file for your app then use INITIAL_URI as said before.

Comment: Did you try a putExtra for the mime type?

Comment: @blackapps I've tried out your solution with INITIAL_URI https://stackoverflow.com/a/67554693/11110509 but it requires an API level of 29. Is there any other way for devices less than?

Comment: Not that i know of.

Comment: After writing the file, if i open the downloads folder programmatically using startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)). File is not visible. But if i open from file explorer of phone, then the file is visible. Any idea, why this is happening ? How to refresh the downloads folder, so that it shows my files created programmatically ?

Comment: How can I directly open a subdirectory under download folder?