# Android 12 - Storage Access Framework / Scoped Storage not working anymore

Tags: android, storage, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage, android-12

**Android 12** recently released on some phones and some users started to complain about storage access: they can't grant access to a specific folder anymore to the app (for example, the "Download" folder).

The message indicates: **"Can't use this folder. To protect your privacy, choose another folder".**

The issue is easy to reproduce and I spent some time looking for a fix, but I could not find an easy one.

[image: Image of the issue]

It seems that the only workarounds are to ask for full storage access (but it's not what I want to do, it's bad) or to ask the user to create a new folder, which would be an UX absolute pain.

What I don't understand is: did Google just - without any documentation - deprecated SAF on Android 12? Is that a bug or a feature? I'm really puzzled there. Android 11 was already such a pain to migrate on, and now I'm afraid that 12 will become even more painful.

Here is the code, but nothing fancy:

```
    /*
    * Requests Scoped Storage access authorization
    */
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @JvmStatic
    fun requestScopedStorageAccess(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int) {
        val storageManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        val intent = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
    }
```

I think that it's worth noting that everything works perfectly on Android 10 & 11, so the issue really is about Android 12.

Comment: "did Google just - without any documentation - deprecated SAF on Android 12?" -- did you try clicking the "Create new folder" button from your screenshot? Did it create a new folder? Did your app gain access to that new folder?

Comment: Yes, this is was I called "workaround 2". It seems that folders created by the app with SAF are the only one the user can grant access to.

Comment: No. All public directories like DCIM, Pictures, Documents are selectable/usable. Only Downloads .. NOT.

Comment: Agreed, users can grant access to lots of folders. On a Pixel 5 running Android 12, using your code, the user can grant access to `Alarms`, `Audiobooks`, `DCIM`, `Documents`, `Movies`, `Music`, `Notifications`, `Pictures`, `Podcasts`, `Recordings`, and `Ringtones`. The user can also grant access to folders that the user created from outside of the app, via USB or via a built-in file manager app. And, you should not need SAF to write your own files to `Downloads` and read them back.

Comment: @CommonsWare, One can write its own files to all the public folders you mentioned. (Except Downloads). Also subfolders can be created everywhere. No SAF needed.

Comment: @blackapps Nice, thanks for noticing this. I just ran more tests and created multiple folders with a folder management app, and I can confirm that only Downloads and the root folder seem not to work atm. There must be more subtlety though, as some users told me that they tried to grant access to a folder previously created by the app (on Android 11?) without any success. Which is even more puzzling now that I know this. I also wonder why Google removed Downloads from this, as it was widely used by apps to backup data (which is also why I was using it).

Comment: `fun requestScopedStorageAccess()` That is a confusing function name. Also you do not have to use `.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()` to show the gui you just get with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, createOpenDocumentTreeIntent() from primaryStorageVolume makes sure that the GUI opens at the root of the folders. Otherwise it opens the latest authorized folder, which was very confusing for some users.

Comment: Not at the root but at root of primary partition. The user can navigate to other partitions though like removable micro sd card. It looks as if there is no root using SAF.

Comment: @CommonsWare "And, you should not need SAF to write your own files to Downloads and read them back." So the app may need to choose whether to use SAF or not based on whether the use will choose to use Downloads or some other folder?

Comment: @LarsH: There, I was referring to direct filesystem access. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html) for more.

Comment: If you came across this post as an end user, I found [this](https://www.androidcentral.com/what-scoped-storage) to be a helpful explainer of what's changed.  [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/j3zgmm/managing_files_in_the_androiddata_folder_on/) lists some file-explorer apps that have been updated to support the new permissions system.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();

            String startSubDir = "Android%2Fdata";

            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

            String scheme = uri.toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

            scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

            scheme += "%3A" + startSubDir;
            Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

            uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

            Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());

            ((Activity) getActivity()).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

            return;
        }
```

Comment: @VGM, you can replace "Android%2Fdata" with "Download", like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-action-open-document-tree-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder