# How to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE without startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I want to select a folder on my phone's SD card. At the moment I am doing this:

```
activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity result!");
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
});
```

..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

How do I get the folder back from the activity? What if I display another activity - how can I tell which activityresult is which?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

The old way of doing things makes sense to me (e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-action-open-document-tree-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder) with request codes and intents), but I don't understand how this is done with the new API calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion stems from using the wrong contract. `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult` is more for cases where you have your own activity and you want to start it and process the result in a custom way. In that case you would return the result in an `Intent` and then use `activityResult.getData()` to get that `Intent` and process it.

For `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` there is no need to do this (and I have no idea what format the Android OS would return, it's probably not documented), you can just use `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`.

> How do I get the folder back from the activity?

Switching to use `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` will allow you to define an `ActivityResultCallback<Uri>` rather than a `ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>`. You can then process the received `Uri` as you normally would.

> What if I display another activity - how can I tell which activityresult is which?

If you are starting another activity, you'd use a different `ActivityResultLauncher` (and have to call `registerForActivityResult` separately for that case, with its own associated callback). The Android OS takes care of calling the correct callback based on the launcher used to launch the activity.