# how to make folder in Download folder by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making Android Studio application in Java.
And I try not to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for upload it to Google Play.
(Google Play Console warned me not to use it.)

When opening the application, I want to make Folder named in "App" in the Download folder.

After getting WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION and READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION, I want to show the download folder and customer to push "save" button to create "App" folder. (See attached image)

I think ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is the best way and I coded like below.

```
//after getting permission
Integer NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE=810;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { if (requestCode ==
                NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE)
        { if (data != null) {
            Uri currentUri = data.getData();
            DocumentFile pickedDir =
                    DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, currentUri);
            DocumentFile newDir =
                    pickedDir.createDirectory("App"); } } }
    }
```

I can go to Internal storage but not Dowoload folder.

How can I go？

The name input field for the newly created folder (default value: App) is not displayed.

How can I show it？

[image: Screenshot_20220614-141001.png]

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67554693/16765223

Comment: Thank you for your advice,M DEV.

It’s done!

Comment: If you successfully created this code. Why not share this with me. I also struggle to create a folder in the Public directory for Scoped Storage. It is good if you share your code with me and other devs.

Comment: just add the solution part to your question.

Answer (score 1):

After getting permission,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
                    String startDir = "Documents";
                    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");
                    String scheme = uri.toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);
                    scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");
                    scheme += "%3A" + startDir;
                    uri = Uri.parse(scheme);
                    intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE);
                    return;
                }
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { if (requestCode ==
                NEW_FOLDER_REQUEST_CODE)
        { if (data != null) {
            Uri currentUri = data.getData();
            DocumentFile pickedDir =
                    DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, currentUri);
            DocumentFile newDir =
                    pickedDir.createDirectory("App"); } } }
    }
```

When this code is executed, Internal storage is shown. [image: Screenshot_20220614-160501]

Choose 「Download」folder and click 「USE THIS FOLDER」and 「ALLOW」.
[image: Screenshot_20220614-160522]

Then 「App」folder is created in 「Download」folder.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort and answer. my problem was `onActivityResult`. I haven't writed this code `DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory("App"); } } }`. Finally, your code is very helpful for me.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work in Android11. In Android10,we can choose 「USE THIS FOLDER」but in 11,we can't choose.