# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE: set initial URI to an external USB hard drive

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, usb-drive

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552027/android-11-action-open-document-tree-set-initial-uri-to-the-documents-folder) which is similar to what I am trying to do.  I have been using this code as my guide.  I would like to have the initial URI be set to an external USB hard drive.  Is this possible?  I have the URI to the external HD, but the code I have been going by does not work. I am requesting permission when the drive is connected, I thought that may be part of my problem.  I am trying to get this to work to save users from having to find the drive themselves.

I have tried getting the URI and path to the drive.  I know the URI from selected the drive and displaying what the URI in the intent was.  I have been trying to use this in the code I am using as a go by, but nothing works.  the File browser always opens to the last place I selected.  I am also requesting permissions on the drive when it is connected to the tablet.  I am expecting the file browser to display and be opened at the root of the external USB HD.